# Why is $2-2\cos(x) = 4\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$?

Tags: trigonometry

As the title states, I was wondering why

$2-2\cos(x) = 4\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$

holds true?

Comment: $1-\cos x=2\sin^2(x/2)$ is a well known identity. You can search it up as "double angle formula".

Comment: What is the variable in these expressions? $x$ or $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formulas $\cos (A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A \sin B$ and $\cos^{2}C+\sin ^{2}C=1$. [ Take $A=B=\frac t 2$].

Comment: Thanks, this exactly what I way missing, really don't know why you got downvoted.